# Interacting with a site that requires a USB device attached to a computer

Tags: usb, remote-desktop, remote-access, remote, remote-control

I've got a finger print reader which has been registered to my desktop. I can use it to fill applications on an online website which requires the fingerprint of the customer. The problem though is that since the fingerprint device is registered to only one computer at a time, there is a bottleneck where i can only process one customer at a time. Also i can't do any other work on my desktop since the fingerprint device is only registered to my desktop and it is in continuous use filling forms due to this.

So I'm looking for some way through which other operators can also fill the form while the fingerprint device is still attached to my computer (The customer can just come to my workstation and give their fingerprint after the form is filled by one of my staff). Is there any way to do that?

Ideally i'd like it so that several operators can fill the form simultaneously. Even if that's not possible, even one operator being able to do it while i can go on doing something else on my desktop would be okay.

PS: The website in question only works on internet explorer. Changing the user-agent won't work because the fingerprint device seems to only work with Internet Explorer. (Edit: The device itself would work with chrome but the website only detects the device on IE)

Comment: I assume you don't want to mention the website, but any details on the fingerprint reader?

Comment: @Arjan The fingerprint reader is a Cogent CSD200. The website is behind a restricted access login so it's not really possible to take a look at it.

Comment: On TV, they just cut off the person's finger and take it to the reader.  Can we assume that isn't an option?

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately i think that'd lead to a significant loss of customers to my competitors, what with their fancy "All fingers still attached" promotions.